# asyc pipe not loading with ngif

Tags: asynchronous, rxjs, observable

I am trying to implement observable catches result of http post operation and displaying result using async pipe with ngif. When I use async pipe without ngif it works fine. - `{{(result | async)}`
But with ngif this doesn't work. Please point the error here.

**page.html File**

```
<div  *ngIf="result | async as quiz; else loading">
        <ion-row>
          <ion-col><div class="small-text ion-text-capitalize ion-text-start" color="medium">
            qz ID:</div></ion-col>
          <ion-col><ion-text><i>{{quiz.quid}}</i> </ion-text></ion-col>
        </ion-row>
</div>
```

**page.ts File**

```
 private results: Observable<QuizDetail>;

doSearch(id:string) {
    let user = this.auth.getUser();
    console.log("searching: user: " + user.connection_key + " " + user.uid + "Quiz:" + id);
    //this.loading = true;
    this.results=this.quizDB.loadQuizDetail(user.connection_key, user.uid, id);
  }
```

**Service class**

```
loadQuizDetail(key:String,uid:String, quid:String):Observable<QuizDetail>{
    var parameters = {
      "connection_key":key,
      "uid":uid,
      "quid":quid
    };
    console.log("going to call post");
    return this.http.post<QuizDetail>(API_URL + '/quiz_detail',
                          JSON.stringify(parameters),httpOptions);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

it's results not result, change it to  **results | async**

```
<div  *ngIf="results | async as quiz; else loading">
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col><div class="small-text ion-text-capitalize ion-text-start" color="medium">
        qz ID:</div></ion-col>
      <ion-col><ion-text><i>{{quiz.quid}}</i> </ion-text></ion-col>
    </ion-row>
</div>
```